# Next JS 13 Dispatch not triggering rerender

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-context, next.js13, rerender

I'm building a Next JS 13 Application (App Directory) and trying to use ContextAPI and reducer to save global states.

Layout.js code (server component):

```
  const cookieStore = cookies()
  const userCookie = cookieStore.get('user')
  const headersList = headers();
  const activePath = headersList.get("x-invoke-path");
  console.log(activePath, userCookie)
  return (   
    <html lang="en">
      <body className={inter.className}>
      <AppProvider>
        {
          (activePath=='/login' || activePath=='/register') ? 
            ((userCookie && userCookie.value) ? redirect('/') : children)
          :
          (userCookie && userCookie.value) || activePath=='/landing' ? 
          <>
            <Navbar user={userCookie}/>
            {children}
          </>:
          redirect('/landing')
        }
      </AppProvider>
      </body>
    </html>    
  )
}
```

Reducer.js code:

```
const reducer = (state,action)=>{
    if(action.type=='add toast'){
        console.log([...state.toasts, action.payload])
        return {...state, toasts: [...state.toasts, action.payload]}
    }
    throw new Error('No action type matched')
}

export default reducer
```

Register/page.js code (client component):

```
const Register = () => {
    const [name, setName] = useState('')
    const [email, setEmail] = useState('')
    const [password, setPassword] = useState('')
    const {state,dispatch} = useContext(AppContext)
    const router = useRouter()

    const handleSubmit = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault()
        console.log('submit called')

        fetch('http://localhost:5000/api/v1/auth/register', {
            cache: 'no-store',
            credentials: 'include',
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                'Content-type': 'application/json',
            },
            body: JSON.stringify({name, email, password}),
        })
        .then((response) => response.json())
        .then((data) => {
            dispatch({type:'add toast', payload:{type:'success', text:`Welcome ${data.user.name}`}})
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            dispatch({type:'add toast', payload:{type:'error', text:error}})
        });
    }

    return (
       <form className="space-y-4 md:space-y-6" onSubmit={(e)=> handleSubmit(e)}>...</form>
    )
}
```

Okay the main problem is that dispatch() runs but does not actually trigger rerender. On the other hand, sometimes I get a bunch of errors in the browser console: Maximum update depth exceeded.

I tried to get around this and use router.push() along with dispatch(), router.push() although works and redirects to '/' after registering but the layout does not get applied to the redirected page. I can't see Navbar on ('/') and neither got a log on console which shows that redirecting using router.push() doesn't go through layout.js

Comment: can you check if `dispatch` updates the state successfully?  can you show the related reducer code, as well?

Comment: @Yilmaz yes, I checked it already and the state is successfully getting updated. I'll edit the question and post the reducer code also

Answer (score 0):

Yes the problem was that I missed the part in the documentation where it says 'Layout.js does not rerender upon navigation.' So I thought dispatch() or router.push() should go through layout.js and authentication should have been applied after registering as a user.